# Error when running hyperledger caliper on hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, caliper, hyperledger-caliper

i have been trying for days to get this working. My problem is that i have a running network with 4 peers (3 peers and 1 orderer) on 4 virtual machines, the network is able to communicate and everything seems to work, my issue is that hyperledger caliper does not want to connect. When i try to run a test with caliper i get this error:

```
error: [composer.js]: composer.init() failed at initialiseFabric(),  code=1, stdout=, stderr=Error: No such container: peer0.org1.example.com
```

I have configured the json file used to get information about the network and the .yaml file for the tests.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the Fabric .yaml file that you are using? What makes you think the network is able to communicate? What this error says is that either you cannot communicate with the machine hosting the peer0.org1 or that machine was unable to run docker-compose.

Comment: The network is able to communicate as I was able to use my application, the issue is how caliper operates with Composer. I posted my issue on this github thread: https://github.com/hyperledger/caliper/issues/360#issuecomment-471531434 and the answer I got was that Caliper is not able to create a channel for a remote network. I dismissed Composer as I needed to use Caliper on my network.